# FREE visualising site builder without database?

Tags: web, responsive-design

I've built a website for a friend, with WordPress & Elementor, which turned out easy and flex. Then I learned some HTML,JS,CSS tuts. Now I want to try some other builder, I watched some tuts about Webflow, which is wonderful visualising CSS, thus, I guess, it will produce more cleaner codes than wordpress? Anyway, some features I need are not free in Webflow, so I have to keep on searching. Anybody, please tell me if any builder could do the followings: (for simple site without blog or ecommerce)

1, without database.....or WordPress is good enought for me.

2, FREE.....including letting me insert js into code, letting me point to my own domain(or, at least could let me export html/css/js code).

3, could let me build a site/project then let my friend (in another city) change headings/texts himself.... is this called front-end editing?

Appreciate any response.